# Can anybody explain about how I set Global Button's target in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, target, uiwindow

If I wrote program in class (use @interface ....in .h and @implementation in .m)
I can set button:target to self but if I want to use in global function, I cannot set button:target as self. I got the error as self"undeclared".

I want to set the target as UIWindow or current display's view.

Can anybody help?

Comment: If you make something global, then it doesn't belong to a class. Therefore, since self refers to the class it is in it wont work.

Comment: Dear anon, I know about that. But I want to use button in Global to call specific global function. I stunned in how to set target in global button.

Comment: You could set a class method witch calls the global function.

Answer (score 0):

A target has to be an object, and an action has to be a method on that object. You can't do what you're trying to do.

If there's some pressing need for a global instance of something, consider making a singleton object and using that as your target.